# How to solve error 550 4.4.7

Tags: exchange-2010

One sender is not able to send us e-mail from external domain because of this problem.
Do you know how to solve it?

error message:
`550 4.4.7 queue.expired; message.expired`

thank you

Comment: It's common practice here to include the full error message with all text, and an NDR if you have a copy.

Comment: Unfortunately I have only printed paper with this information. Are some headers needed?

Comment: Really just more of the error message, so what you have edited into your question will be more helpful.

Comment: This is all I have, there is not much info. I'm trying [this](http://www.theemailadmin.com/2010/05/troubleshooting-exchange-server-error-4-4-7/) troubleshooting but that's for Exchange 2003.

Comment: If you have FIM, please review contact object of this user

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SMTP Extended Error 4.4.7 equates to:

```
4.x.x = Persistent Transient Failure
x.4.x = Network and Routing Status
x.x.7 = Delivery time expired
```

This correlates with the message you have reported with this error.

The most common cause for this error is that your message was held for an extended period of time at an intermediate relay server because that server could not connect to the 'next' server the message was to be delivered to.  Typically this will be either an ISP's relay server which could not deliver to an end-user server, or a corporate edge server which could not deliver to a final mailbox store server.

In your case, it sounds like your senders mail server (or their ISP's relay mail server) is unable to connect to your mail server to deliver the message to you.  I've seen this before where the sending mail server is behind an improperly configured firewall - specifically one configured to drop packets to / from [bogons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bogon_filtering).  It's difficult to be 100% certain if this is your issue without also seeing the `Received:` headers from the NDR, but this is one fairly likely scenario.  Ask your message sender to check their firewall logs at the time they are trying to send a message to you to verify this.

Comment: This is the received header (there is only one) `Received: from a.b.com ([10.2.0.14]) by a ([10.2.0.14]) with mapi id x.x.x.x.x; date and time - 0500`

Comment: I assume `10.2.0.14` is not one of your IP Addresses?

Comment: Yes, we have another non-public range.

Comment: OK, so the message never leaves the senders server - there are only a couple of key places you can look, either: 1. the senders server is improperly configured, 2. the senders firewall is improperly configured and won't allow a connection to your server, 3. your firewall is improperly configured and is rejecting the connection from the sending server or 4. your `MX` records are improperly configured in the public DNS (this last option is quite unlikely as I assume you're receiving other messages).

Answer (score 3):

The general problem is due a bad DNS configuration. First the mail servers recieve your ip and fqdn, then they do a query and if there is a response take the ip of the answer and do a reverse query if it is the same with the fqdn then the mail is accepted alse it will answer with a

```
450 4.7.1 Client host rejected: cannot find your hostname
```

and in your system will get

```
550 4.4.7 queue.expired; message.expired
```

due a no response from the remote server because you did not configure your DNS correctly.

Answer (score 2):

I'm seeing this problem right now.

The sender SMTP server is running Microsoft SMTP Server.  It is connecting initially to spamd on OpenBSD to do greylisting.  Once it successfully passes that, it should go to the OpenSMTP server on the same server.

It appears that the Microsoft SMTP Server is connecting to spamd and then dropping the connection without actually trying to send the message.

Typically, if it tries to send the message and the spamd tells it to try again later, the failure notice will report the message from spamd.  In this case, the customer's failure notice that they sent to me only contains:

```
#< #4.4.7 smtp;550 4.4.7 QUEUE.Expired; message expired> #SMTP#
```

That tells me that it is either never receiving any kind of a rejection message (i.e. does not make any attempt try to deliver the message) or their server is not reporting that message.  In either case, it seems to me that their mail server is either broken or misconfigured.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and it was a DNS issue.
On the Exchange server drop to an admin command prompt and see if you can resolve the MX records for the domain.

```
nslookup

set q=mx

example.com
```

If it cant resolve the mx records its a dns issue. You can check the domain's MX records on http://mxtoolbox.com/ to see what they should be.

To fix my issue, i went to my local dns server, removed all my dns forwards. I placed my ISP dns server within the Root Hints. Cleared the cache, stop & started DNS service.

From an Admin command prompt, run: `ipconfig /flushdns`
This resolved my issues.

Answer (score -3):

Your Server can see the other server through the firewall and right DNS
But try to check your server TLS setting since some server cannot establish connection with other unless there is an encrypted channel